# Is it possible to temporarily disable event in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code in 'saved' model event:

```
Session::flash('info', 'Data has been saved.')`
```

so everytime the model is saved I can have a flash message to inform users. The problem is, sometimes I just need to update a field like 'status' or increment a 'counter' and I don't need a flash message for this. So, is it possible to temporarily disable triggering the model event? Or is there any Eloquent method like `$model->save()` that doesn't trigger 'saved' event?

Answer (score 187):

### Solution for Laravel 8.x and 9.x

With Laravel 8 it became even easier, just use `saveQuietly` method:

```php
$user = User::find(1);
$user->name = 'John';

$user->saveQuietly();
```

[Laravel 8.x docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#saving-a-single-model-without-events)
[Laravel 9.x docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#saving-a-single-model-without-events)

---

### Solution for Laravel 7.x, 8.x and 9.x

On Laravel 7 (or 8 or 9) wrap your code that throws events as per below:

```php
$user = User::withoutEvents(function () use () {
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->name = 'John';
    $user->save();

    return $user;
});
```

[Laravel 7.x docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#muting-events)
[Laravel 8.x docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#muting-events)
[Laravel 9.x docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#muting-events)

---

### Solution for Laravel versions from 5.7 to 6.x

The following solution works **from the Laravel version 5.7 to 6.x**, for older versions check the second part of the answer.

In your model add the following function:

```
public function saveWithoutEvents(array $options=[])
{
    return static::withoutEvents(function() use ($options) {
        return $this->save($options);
    });
}
```

Then to save without events proceed as follow:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->name = 'John';

$user->saveWithoutEvents();
```

For more info check the [Laravel 6.x documentation](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.html#method_withoutEvents)

---

### Solution for **Laravel 5.6 and older versions**.

In Laravel 5.6 (and previous versions) you can **disable and enable again** the event observer:

```
// getting the dispatcher instance (needed to enable again the event observer later on)
$dispatcher = YourModel::getEventDispatcher();

// disabling the events
YourModel::unsetEventDispatcher();

// perform the operation you want
$yourInstance->save();

// enabling the event dispatcher
YourModel::setEventDispatcher($dispatcher);
```

For more info check the [Laravel 5.5 documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setEventDispatcher)

Comment: this answer was great at the time it was written, but there's a cleaner way now, [using `withoutEvents()` below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55931917/102960) :)

Comment: @Dan this is amazing. I did not know about `saveQuietly()` but worked for me. And thank you for keeping this post updated as Laravel changes! You Da man, DAN!

Comment: What about Model::create() method on Laravel 8? How to stop events with create() method?

Comment: An even better solution seems to be the trait `WithoutEvents` which can be used in any `TestCase`

Answer (score 48):

There is a nice solution, from Taylor's Twitter page:

Add this method to your base model, or if you don't have one, create a trait, or add it to your current model

```
public function saveQuietly(array $options = [])
{
    return static::withoutEvents(function () use ($options) {
        return $this->save($options);
    });
}
```

Then in you code, whenever you need to save your model without events get fired, just use this:

```
$model->foo = 'foo';
$model->bar = 'bar';

$model->saveQuietly();
```

Very elegant and simple :)

Comment: For reference, this was added with this PR: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27419

Comment: awesome, tks so much !

Comment: is there also a function updateQuietly() or this one can be used instead?

Comment: Here is a full trait that implements both `saveQuiety()` and `updateQuietly()`. Change the namespace as needed. https://gist.github.com/squatto/4b8c541c2c8f6bce700bc0f700cb34ac

Comment: @ScottCarpenter The updateQuietly didn't work for me. It still triggers the saving() function of my model

Comment: @HiradRoshandel that's strange. What version of Laravel are you using it with?

Comment: @ScottCarpenter We are using 5.8

Answer (score 14):

Call the model Object then call unsetEventDispatcher
after that you can do whatever you want without worrying about Event triggering

like this one:

```
    $IncidentModel = new Incident;
    $IncidentModel->unsetEventDispatcher();

    $incident = $IncidentModel->create($data);
```

Answer (score 10):

To answer the question for anyone who ends up here looking for the solution, you can disable model listeners on an instance with the [`unsetEventDispatcher()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_unsetEventDispatcher) method:

```
$flight = App\Flight::create(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
$flight->unsetEventDispatcher();
$flight->save(); // Listeners won't be triggered
```

Comment: Won't the creating and created event trigger fire at the first line ??

Comment: You make a good point; For my purposes, though, I was interested in suppressing "save" events from being triggered, and this did the job.

Comment: I guessed so :)

Comment: @AndySoell do I have to run setEventDispatcher to enable events again after save? I tried to do that $flight->setEventDispatcher(); but I got: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setEventDispatcher(), 0 passed ... How do I restore events again after I am done?

Comment: @nikocraft Without having tried it myself, I would attempt to do a `$flight->fresh()` or `$flight->refresh()`, which in theory gives your variable a new copy of the model instance. I would imagine that means re-enabled observers.

Answer (score 5):

In laravel 7.x you can do that as easy as

```
use App\User;

$user = User::withoutEvents(function () {
    User::findOrFail(1)->delete();

    return User::find(2);
});
```

See more in [Laravel 7.x Muting Events documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#muting-events)

Answer (score 5):

In laravel 8.x :

**Saving A Single Model Without Events**

Sometimes you may wish to "save" a given model without raising any events. You may accomplish this using the saveQuietly method:

```php
$user = User::findOrFail(1);

$user->name = 'Victoria Faith';

$user->saveQuietly();
```

[See Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldnt be mixing session flashing with model events - it is not the responsibility of the model to notify the session when something happens.

It would be better for your controller to call the session flash when it saves the model.

This way you have control over when to actually display the message - thus fixing your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At first I thought it can automate the flash message so I don't need to repeatly put it in controllers, as for model's responsibility I think it's not the model who notifies the session, the model just fires the event, it doesn't know what the listener of the event is doing, does it? But anyway, I think it's better to put it in the controller as you said, since it seems there is no way to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a long time since the question, I've found a way to turn off all events at once. In my case, I'm making a migration script, but I don't want any event to be fired (either from Eloquent or any other).

The thing is to get all the events from the Event class and remove them with the forget method.

Inside my command:

```
$events = Event::getRawListeners();
foreach ($events as $event_name => $closure) {
    Event::forget($event_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was using the trait `WithoutEvents`. This will be executed inside the `setUp` method and does prevent any `dispatch` you have added to the code.