# How to prevent Model events from firing using phpunit?

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-4, laravel-5, phpunit

I want to prevent Model events such as 'created'. 'updated' etc when testing my application using phpunit.

In the documentation of Laravel it says that you can prevent events from firing by using

`$this->expectsEvents(App\Events\UserRegistered::class);`

But in my situation I have no class to expect.

Even if I use `$this->withoutEvents();` to prevent all events, eloquent events are fired.

How can I prevent eloquent events?

Comment: Have you tried to create a mock with the Mockery package? I think that should help.

Comment: No I haven't. Can you be more specific?

Comment: This is the mockery repo, you should check it out and the docs https://github.com/padraic/mockery

Comment: This does not solve my question.

Answer (score 13):

Looking into Laravel Api `Model::flushEventListeners()` should "Remove all of the event listeners for the model."

EDIT

You can write a custom method base on this one:

```
public static function flushEventListeners()
{
    if (! isset(static::$dispatcher)) {
        return;
    }
    $instance = new static;
    foreach ($instance->getObservableEvents() as $event) {
        static::$dispatcher->forget("eloquent.{$event}: ".get_called_class());
    }
}
```

Something like this maybe:

```
public static function flushEventListenersProvided($events)
{
    if (! isset(static::$dispatcher)) {
        return;
    }
    $instance = new static;
    foreach ($instance->getObservableEvents() as $event) {
        if(in_array($event, $events)){
          static::$dispatcher->forget("eloquent.{$event}: ".get_called_class());
        }
    }
}
```

and maybe add it as a trait to the models, or a base model that all your models will extend. This code is untested but should give you an idea of how it can be done.

Comment: this is very useful but in my situation I want to prevent only some model events. For example 'saved' or 'creating' or etc.

Comment: this seems to work fine but I dont want to add this function to all my models that need to be tested. It has to be a way to do it directly from my test file.

Comment: I couldn't find anything else in the documentation. I suggested creating a trait and including it in the models or creating a base model for all your models, putting it there and extending all the models from it.

Answer (score 8):

If you really just want to disable the model's observer, such as `creating`, `created`, `updated`, etc. then you can call the model's façade method `unsetEventDispatcher`.

For example, you can place it in the test class's `setUp` method. And you don't have to reset it in `tearDown` because the framework automatically does this in `setUp` for the next test.

```php
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();
    App\MyModel::unsetEventDispatcher();
}
```

If you want this to be temporary, then look into [`withoutEventDispatcher`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27419).

Also you could `getEventDispatcher` and save that to a temporary variable then `setEventDispatcher` again after you've completed your business as is demonstrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51301753/4233593

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**

You can prevent model events from firing by mocking the Observer. Here's how:

```
public function my_sexy_test()
    {
        $this->app->bind(MyModelObserver::class, function () {
            return $this->getMockBuilder(MyModelObserver::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
        });

        factory(MyModel::class)->states('pending')->create([
                'user_id' => 1,
                'publisher_revenue' => 10,
        ]);

 // Your test logic goes here
}
```

**Method 2:**

You can call the following in your setUp() method:

```
 MyModel::unsetEventDispatcher();
```

**Both Tested and working in Laravel 5.6.**

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `shouldReceive` method of the `Model` class. Basically the `Model` class extends `Mockery`.
Here's an example assuming you have a class `Car`:

```
Car::shouldReceive('save')->once();
```

This will not hit the database but will use a mock instead. You can find more info on Laravel testing here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing

Hope this helps.

Comment: this does not answer your initial question but is more of an alternative

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
$model = new App\Model($inputs);

$this->expectsEvents(['eloquent.creating: App\Model', 'eloquent.saved: App\Model']);

$model->save();
```

Comment: Have tried this solution?
It returns an exception
`EventTest::testExample
Exception: The following events were not fired: [eloquent.creating: App\Model]`

I have tried with different events too.

Comment: I have used Log to track all the fired events and 'eloquent.creating: App\Model' is one of the fired ones. I cant understand why Mockery cannot catch it.

Comment: After a lot of tests I found out that this never works, even when mockery does not trigger errors.

Comment: Does anyone know *why* this doesn't work? I would say it should, but what's the alternative here?