# Laravel Observers - updated triggers itself endlessly and produces a bcrypt error

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing an error that I would like to see explained. I have an UserObserver and every time a user gets updated and the `active` field updates to true a new password is generated and a welcome email is sent.

The function looks like this.

```
    public function updated (User $user)
    {
        if ($user->active && $user->isDirty('active')) {
            $password = generatePassword();
            $user->password = bcrypt($password);
            $user->save();

            $user->notify(
                new UserWelcomeNotification(
                    $user->email,
                    $password,
                    new MailResource(Email::getMailInfo(23))
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

As you can see in the if statement there is a check to see if the user is active and if the database field has been changed (`isDirty()`). If this is true a new password is being generated, hashed with bcrypt and then send to the user via notifications. (mail)
As expected the password update triggers the method again, but now the `isDirty('active)` should return false. This does not happen, it returns true through all the iterations. After the PHP max execution time has been reached I get the following error:

> [Fri Jan 11 09:13:13 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of
>   60 seconds exceeded in
>   app/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php

After enabling xdebug the following exception is thrown. (as expected)

> PHP Error:  Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
>   in
>   /home/ilyas/script/clockwork/app/src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php
>   on line 1971

From this issue, which can be solved easily, I have 2 questions.

Why does bcrypt thow an error after the max execution time has been reached?

Why does `$user->isDirty('active')` return true throughout after every update in this loop although the last update in the observer did not update the `active` field?

As asked by Mozammil `$user->getDirty()` returns this the first time the updated method is triggered.

```
array(2) {
  'active' =>
  bool(true)
  'updated_at' =>
  string(19) "2019-01-11 11:27:13"
}
```

From the second time it returns until timeout is reached:

```
array(3) {
  'password' =>
  string(60) "$2y$10$rlAbpelKnT/yp5zFhXcjwelEKkDEx5SfNJWqL1LiDltRnHYBLINmK"
  'active' =>
  bool(true)
  'updated_at' =>
  string(19) "2019-01-11 11:27:13"
}
```

Comment: You should not update same model on updated event, it will obviously go to infinite loop.

Comment: @sumitsharma That was not my question. I already said in the question that it could be fixed easily. The fact that bcrypt throws an error and `isDirty('active')` keeps returning true is the question.

Comment: I am curious. Could you `dd($user->getDirty())` so that we know which values Laravel thinks is dirty?

Comment: @Mozammil I have updated my question with the output of `getDirty()`

Comment: I am taking a look at the API. I am having a hard time understanding the difference between `isDirty()` and `wasChanged()`. I think `$user->wasChanged('active')` might solve it. However, I need to give it a try myself.

Comment: @Mozammil I was doing the exact same thing. Currently, I am tinkering with `getChanges()` and `wasChanged()`. Both seem to do the exact same thing as `getDirty()` and `isDirty()`

Comment: @IlyasDeckers No luck with wasChanged() as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186525/discussion-between-ilyas-deckers-and-mozammil).

Comment: @Mozammil Two persons on GitHub have provided an answer and these actually make sense.

Comment: I found the final solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407818/is-it-possible-to-temporarily-disable-event-in-laravel/51301753 Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Dries Vints and Jonas Staudenmeir for providing an answer on GitHub.

From DriesVints:

> Well, think about it. The "updated" event happens after your model was
>   updated. So any changes you made on your model are bound to still be
>   picked up by the isDirty call. The fact that $user->active returns
>   true is indeed because it was changed to true from the original
>   update. The original changes aren't cleared or anything. Since you are
>   constantly referencing the same object being passed to the updated
>   method this is the expected behaviour.

From Jonas Staudenmeir

> This is happening because the updated event is fired before
>   syncOriginal() is called.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27138

Comment: Thanks. It does :)

Comment: That was a shit answer from them. A good answer would have been something like "just include 'this' with the observer update to make it not trigger itself"

Comment: Here is a real answer to the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407818/is-it-possible-to-temporarily-disable-event-in-laravel/51301753  
  
unsetEventDispatcher()

Comment: @CptMisery I did not know about that method, thanks!

Comment: How to stop this. I am having the same issue and it keeps on sending emails even I stopped the server.

Answer (score 0):

You call `Model#save` inside of `Observer#updated` which will thus trigger another "cycle" of `Observer#updated`. You can call `Model#saveQuietly` or use `Model::withoutEvents` instead to avoid this kind of loops.