# Observer not triggering updated event when input not changed - Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8, observer-pattern

I'm testing in Postman & the below code works fine if am clicking on `send` button of `postman` with a new input data. But if am clicking the `send` button of postman 2nd time without changing any input datas, it creates a log entry `1 file viewed` instead of `1 file inserted`. What's wrong with my code?

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request,$id){  
        
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                
                'orderId'    => 'required|integer',
                'fileId'    => 'required|integer',
                'status'    => 'required|string'
            ]
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
        }

        $data=tap(FileLogs::find($id))->update(['orderId'=>$request->orderId,'fileId'=>$request->fileId,'status'=>$request->status]);
       
        if($data){
            return response()->json(['status'=>'success','StatusCode'=> 200,'message'=>'Successfully Updated','data'=>$data]);
           
        }
        else{
            return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed','message'=>'Update Failed'],400);
        }
    }
   
  public function view($id){ 
    
    
        $data = FileLogs::where('id',$id)->get(['orderId','fileId','status']);
        if(count($data)<1){
            return response()->json(['status'=>'Failed','message'=>'Failed to Fetch Data'],400);
        }
        else{
                return response()->json(['status'=>'success','StatusCode'=> 200,'message'=>'Successfully Fetched Data','data'=>$data]);
        }
               
}
```

**Observer**

```
public function updated(FileLogs $fileLogs)
    {
        FilesChangeLogs::create([
                'fileId' => $fileLogs->fileId,
                'logDetails' => '1 file updated',
                'modifiedBy' => Auth::user()->id
            ]);      
    }

  public function retrieved(FileLogs $fileLogs)
{
    FilesChangeLogs::create([
        'fileId' => $fileLogs->fileId,
        'logDetails' => '1 file viewed',
        'modifiedBy' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    'prefix' => 'file-logs',
], function () {
    Route::get('read/{id}', 'FileLogController@view');
    Route::post('update/{id}', 'FileLogController@update');
});
```

Comment: Please add your routes, and add the route you are posting to. These are just 2 methods.

Comment: @frogeyedman see the updated question. i have added routes too

Comment: and to what route are you post or getting ?

Comment: i'm using `POST` method for update & `GET` method for view

Comment: yes... " the below code works fine if am clicking on send button of postman with a new input data." to what url are you sending data ?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file-logs/update/9  - using a postman url like this for update.

Comment: Please check this thread, this way we can help you solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @frogeyedman u shared the link to know how to ask a good question. What is wrong with my question

Answer (score 2):

The `FileLogs::find($id)` method in the Controller triggers the `retrieved()` method on the Observer. Thats where the `1 file viewed` message comes from.

You mentioned calling the `api/file-logs/update/{id}` endpoint multiple times. The first time, it does trigger the `updated()` method on the Observer. The second time the endpoint is called with the **exact same payload**, it does not trigger the `updated()` method on the Observer.

The reason for this is that `updated()` is **only** called if a model was updated. Since you are sending the exact same data for the second time, the `FileLog` model was not updated and will therefore not trigger `updated()` on the Observer.

Comment: so, is it not an error? can't i resolve this issue?

Comment: It is not an error, it is expected behaviour. Only when the model is actually updated with new values. the Observer will be triggered.

You can use the `saving()` or `saved()` method instead of `updated()` method in your Observer. You could also probably use `updating()`. For more information check the [docs about Eloquent model events](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events). If you really want to use `updated()`, you have to create an extra column on your model (like a counter) and simply update every time. But this might not be what you want.

Comment: using `updating` event in observer gives the same result

Comment: using `saving` & `saved` events in observer add 2 log entries such as `1 file viewed` & `1 file updated` to the db , even if new input data is given for updating

Comment: The`1 file viewed` is fired because of the `find()` method. The `saving()` and `saved()` events fire when a model is saving or was saved respectively, therefore inserting the `1 file updated`. This is what you want to achieve right?

Comment: i don't want to see the `1 file viewed` msg in update operation

Comment: That is because `find()` is called and is expected behaviour. If you want to prevent this from happening, you have to remove `find()` and rely on the query builder to update:

`FileLogs::where('id', $id)->update(['orderId'=>$request->orderId,'fileId'=>$request->fileId,'status'=>$request->status]);`. You can then also remove `tap()`.

Comment: You can also disable events temporarily, see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407818/is-it-possible-to-temporarily-disable-event-in-laravel) on StackOverflow

Comment: but i want to return the updated data. the code u mentioned won't give that

Comment: You can temporarily disable events as shown in my previous answer. You would have to  split the statements up however.