# Laravel observer - deleted and forceDeleted both fired

Tags: laravel

I use SoftDeletes trait in my model, and an Observer which works great for every event.

But when i forceDelete a model, both deleted and forceDeleted methods are fired, so my notifications are fired twice.

The only thread i found got no answers :
https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/36191

Is there anyway to "quiet" the deleted method or something similar ?

Any help appreciated !
Julien

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to temporarily disable event in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407818/is-it-possible-to-temporarily-disable-event-in-laravel)

Comment: No, i use Quietly, but this is not the use case. I can't perform deleteQuietly to forceDelete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using both events, the only way is for you to check in your `deleted` event if it is coming from a force deletion and then stop further execution.

```
if ($model->isForceDeleting()) {
    return null; // Stop the rest of the event
}
```

Or as you mention, the reverse

```
if (! $model->isForceDeleting()) {
    // Deleted event code here
}
```

Comment: Yes i guess thie is the right way... In deleted method if (!$model->isForceDeleting()) perform actions

Answer (score 0):

i think you should comment that deleted function in observer. i think this will work try this. keep only one function there which is forceDeleted

Comment: I have different event fired if i delete or forceDelete, i need both... I guess i will have to test if isFoceDeleting() in the deleted method

Comment: then you should check before hitting the each of function then it  will work i think so also